# How to remove xmlns attribute from root element by using xmldocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XmlDocument for removing xmlns attribute from following xml:

```
<Root xmlns="http://my.namespace">
    <Product>
        <Rest of the document />
    </Product>
</Root>
```

I want output like following:

```
<Root>
    <Product>
        <Rest of the document/>
    </Product>
</Root>
```

I can remove this by using xdocument. But Is there any way to delete this by using XmlDocument?

Comment: Tell me if my answer helps

Comment: Is this the only way to remove xmlns attribute? your code looks big for removing this atleast one xmlns attribute. any simple method avail? @NoamM

Comment: I'm sure there is anotwer ways, that the one I now (from that nice blog).